# La canneberge a-t-elle disparu?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, alimentation

J'ai l'impression de [voir](http://www.creapharma.ch/cranberry.htm) et d'entendre (radio, TV, collègues...) de plus en plus souvent le mot *cranberry*, employé en lieu et place de *canneberge*, en France. 

<sup>(Et je grogne à chaque fois.)</sup>

Il semble que cet usage n'a pas d'acceptation formelle: [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canneberge), le Robert (petit, 2010), n'en font pas mention. [L'académie](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/generic/showp.exe?14;s=384425760;p=pseudomen.txt) non plus, dans sa version en ligne. Enfin, je n'ai pas souvenir d'avoir entendu ou vu ce mot employé dans la langue française avant 2005 ou 2010.

Pourtant, [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cranberry%2Ccanneberge&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccranberry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccanneberge%3B%2Cc0) donne une vision très différente de cette évolution:

[image]

Ceci me surprend - c'est un euphémisme - et tend à donner tort à mon impression:

- *Cranberry* semble avoir toujours été plus ou moins usité, avec un sursaut vers la fin des années 90 qui pourrait donner l'impression d'une arrivée soudaine.
- Mais *canneberge* a connu un essor plus fort encore, et ce dès la fin des années 80. Aujourd'hui, à en croire cette courbe, on devrait le voir bien plus souvent que *cranberry*

C'est d'autant plus clair si l'on ne s'intéresse qu'aux quarante dernière années:
[image]

Comment expliquer ce décalage? L'un serait-il utilisé par la presse et l'industrie tandis que l'autre serait plutôt employé dans des publications spécialisées, de type recherche, par exemple ?

Comment: C'est dans un documentaire TV de 2009, [Cap Cod, le temps des cranberries](http://www.arte.tv/guide/fr/042395-000/360-geo), que j'ai appris le mot français _canneberge_.

Comment: On rencontre aussi _airelles_ dans ce sens (même si ma compréhension est que ce mot est plus générique que _canneberge_)

Comment: Au Québec, je n'ai *jamais* entendu *cranberry* en français, toujours, systématiquement, *canneberge*.

Comment: @Kareen Loués soient le Québec et les québécois :)

Comment: Je note qu'au corpus 2009, le mot d'origine iroquoienne [atoca](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canneberge%2Ccranberry%2Catoca%2Cataca%2Cairelle+des+marais%2C&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccanneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccranberry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catoca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cataca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cairelle%20des%20marais%3B%2Cc0) dépasse légèrement le terme anglais.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Et ce depuis 1989!

Comment: @Unfrancophone :  +1 , j'ai personnellement toujours connu "airelles" et pensais qu'il s'agissait d'un synonyme quand j'ai plus tard découvert canneberge, comme traduction de cranberry d'ailleurs. Je viens juste de découvrir qu'il s'agissait d'un terme plus générique, la myrtille étant une airelle, comme la canneberge.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canneberge) indique :

> La canneberge, [...] ou encore souvent appelée par son nom anglais dans les produits industriels en Europe, **cranberry**, est un arbrisseau [...].

Et plus loin :

> #### Dénominations
>
> En France, on nomme cette plante également grande airelle rouge d’Amérique du Nord. Cependant le terme anglais « cranberry » tend à s'imposer en France, parce que l'industrie agroalimentaire (principalement une société américaine) et l'industrie cosmétique privilégient pour leurs produits ce terme anglophone

---

Voir la [référence 6](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canneberge#cite_note-6) de l'article au sujet de la société *Ocean Spray*; on remarquera aussi que cette appellation *cranberry* est faite sur le site français et non sur le site québécois.

Comment: Merci Yohann. Oui, j'ai également vu cette page avant d'écrire. Elle correspond à l'observation que je fais, et qui pourtant est contredite par les statistiques d'usage de *ngram*. D'où ma question...

Comment: @Shlublu Si ta question est **Est-ce que l'appelation *cranberry* est officielle?** La réponse est non, je n'ai pas trouvé non plus un seul dictionnaire en faisant une référence officielle. Je répondais plutôt à la question **Vu que l'appellation n'est pas officielle, pourquoi ces statistiques?** Dont la réponse est : **L'industrie l'utilise.** Si après, tu te demandes pourquoi l'industrie l'utilise, je dirais que c'est que ce sont souvent des multinationales.

Comment: Ça fait partie de ce qui me surprend: "l'industrie l'utilise", ça fait s'attendre à une augmentation de l'utilisation du mot *cranberry*, et à une diminution ou une stagnation du mot *canneberge*. Or c'est l'inverse que l'on voit: *canneberge* explose après 2000, là où *cranberry* n'a qu'un petit sursaut qui retombe, pour rester à peu près aussi utilisé qu'il l'a toujours été. C'est vraiment surprenant !

Comment: Ma question est mal rédigée cependant, c'est ton commentaire qui me permet de le voir. Je vais l'améliorer.

Comment: @Shlublu peut être que cette augmentation est due à une *réaction* des médias ou d'une marque bio de parler d'un produit en l'appelant par son nom francophone et en mettant en exergue notre devoir de conservation de notre patrimoine ... Je ne sais pas

Answer (score 2):

En complément, hormis l'impact très contemporain que pourrait avoir une [société](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13700) en particulier, il m'apparaît difficile de tirer une conclusion au sujet de l'usage du mot anglais au [*corpus*](http://aclweb.org/anthology/P/P12/P12-3029.pdf) français...

En décortiquant les [résultats](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_ROOT_%3D%3Ecanneberge%2C*%20canneberge%2C%28_START_%20Cranberry%20%2B%20Cranberry%20Township%20%2B%20de%20Cranberry%29%2Ccranberry%2Ccanneberge%2Catoca%2Cataca%2Cairelle%20*_ADJ%2Cairelle%20des%20marais%2C*_ADP%20Cranberry&year_start=1965&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_ROOT_%3D%3Ecanneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20canneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bla%20canneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bde%20canneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bairelle%20canneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bou%20canneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28_START_%20Cranberry%20%2B%20Cranberry%20Township%20%2B%20de%20Cranberry%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccranberry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccanneberge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catoca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cataca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cairelle%20*_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bairelle%20rouge_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bairelle%20myrtille_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cairelle%20des%20marais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde_ADP%20Cranberry%3B%2Cc0) pour « cranberry », on voit des interférences de la part de *toponymes* ([US](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=136:2:0::NO:RP::), [Canada](http://www4.rncan.gc.ca/search-place-names/search?q=Cranberry&category=O&sort-field=), aussi [ici](http://geonames.nga.mil/namesgaz/), deux entrées supplémentaires en Irlande), de [patronymes](http://forebears.co.uk/surnames/cranberry). Qui plus est, on retrouve semble-t-il une vaste quantité de textes en anglais, soit directement (voir [inversement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canneberge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccanneberge%3B%2Cc0) au corpus anglais dans une moindre mesure), soit se [trouvant](https://books.google.com/books?id=ccDtAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cranberry%22&dq=%22cranberry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TV89VdPqLu2IsQTvlID4Cw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ) à l'intérieur d'une publication avec un titre en français par exemple ?? C'est sans compter les multiples possibilités de variantes du [genre](https://books.google.com/books?id=ovbNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cranberry%22&dq=%22cranberry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ENs8Va-XPNHisAS694CgDg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCA) « *le cranberry en anglais c'est la canneberge* » c'est-à-dire le cas de *dictionnaires*, parfois bilingues, et divers contenus en [lexicographie](https://books.google.com/books?id=WIEdAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cranberry%22&dq=%22cranberry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rmg9VduxKJDLsASJrYCoBA&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCTgy); dans ces cas, plus on parle de canneberge, plus on parle de cranberry. Il n'est pas clair comment l'on doit [débusquer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28cranberry%20-%20Cranberry%20Township%20-%20_START_%20Cranberry%20-%20de%20Cranberry%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28cranberry%20-%20Cranberry%20Township%20-%20%20_START_%20Cranberry%20-%20de%20Cranberry%29%3B%2Cc0) tout ça avec l'interface (*cranberry* en début de phrase sans article etc. est-il un indice), mais qu'on parle du mot anglais et qu'on en disserte ne nous apprend rien sur l'usage consistant à l'utiliser au lieu de canneberge. Il faut enlever le lissage des résultats pour mieux sentir l'impact des données brutes sur la courbe. Quand *canneberge/cranberry* s'alignent à l'an 2000, est-ce un ensemble de documents bilingues qui sont entrés au corpus ? En [1959](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry) il y a eu des craintes au sujet des pesticides utilisés dans la production à l'époque (*cranberry cancer scare*); on aurait pu penser que c'eût été reflété de manière significative visuellement: non. Il faut connaître la date exacte de l'introduction en grand volume du jus de canneberge en France par la grande entreprise pour voir, parce que ce qui précède semble peu significatif.

Il faudrait accéder au corpus [brut](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html), enlever les textes anglais et tous les éléments identifiés puis utiliser des requêtes mieux adaptées pour voir si il y a des tendances. Dans tous les cas à mon avis ça semble être une entreprise périlleuse considérant ce qui a été dit, et peut-être faut-il justement utiliser un corpus davantage spécialisé.

Comment: Je ne m'étais pas rendu compte de tous ces biais. C'est limpide. Enfin, le fait que ce n'est pas gagné est limpide... Merci Amphiteóth!

Answer (score 1):

Quand le mot français existe, pourquoi utiliser le mot anglais, même si l'industrie agro-alimentaire tente de vous l'imposer? Venez faire un tour au Québec, vous achèterez et consommerez des canneberges.

Anglophones will buy cranberries.